# Custom UIView Not Showing Accessibility on Voice Over

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone, accessibility, uiaccessibility

I'm trying to get voice over working with an openGL view, specifically from the cocos2d framework.

From the Apple Accessibility guide I followed this section: [Make the Contents of Custom Container Views Accessible](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iPhoneAccessibility/Making_Application_Accessible/Making_Application_Accessible.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008785-CH102-SW9)

I've subclassed the view (CCGLView for cocos2d people), which is a UIView, to implement the informal UIAccessibilityContainer protocol.

**UIAccessibilityContainer implementation in my subclassed UIView:**

```
-(NSArray *)accessibilityElements{
return [self.delegate accessibleElements];
}

-(BOOL)isAccessibilityElement{
return NO;
}
-(NSInteger)accessibilityElementCount{
return [self accessibilityElements].count;
}
-(NSInteger)indexOfAccessibilityElement:(id)element{
return [[self accessibilityElements] indexOfObject:element];
}
-(id)accessibilityElementAtIndex:(NSInteger)index{
return [[self accessibilityElements] objectAtIndex:index];
}
```

This code is getting called and `-(NSArray *)acessibilityElements` is returning an array of UIAccessibilityElements.  However the voice over controls are not showing up when I touch the screen.  Any ideas on what I'm missing or doing wrong?

**Other Information:**

I'm using a storyboard and adding the CCGLView to the UIView in the storyboard.  The _director.view is the CCGLView that I subclassed.

```
 // Add the director as a child view controller.
[self addChildViewController:_director];

// Add the director's OpenGL view, and send it to the back of the view hierarchy so we can place UIKit elements on top of it.
[self.view addSubview:_director.view];
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:_director.view];
```

For a while I suspected that because I added the subview that this was causing it not to show up, but I also tried subclassing the UIView in the storyboard the same way but it was also not working.

Also this is how I am creating each UIAccessibilityElement in the array.

```
UIAccessibilityElement *elm = [[UIAccessibilityElement alloc] initWithAccessibilityContainer:view];
    elm.accessibilityFrame = f;
    elm.accessibilityLabel = t.letter;
    elm.isAccessibilityElement = YES;
    elm.accessibilityHint = @"Button";
    elm.accessibilityValue = t.letter;
    elm.accessibilityTraits = UIAccessibilityTraitButton;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found a solution that is working now, in case anyone has this problem.  `-(id)accessibilityElementAtIndex:(NSInteger)index` was returning a proper`UIAccessibilityElement` but it looks like it wasn't getting retained by whatever Accessibility API is using it.  I made a strong NSArray property to hold the UIAccessibilityElements and now it is working fine.